# ¿Como usar 2 botones en un beginform asp.net mvc para obtener y registrar datos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

He creado un formulario `Html.BeginForm` con 2 botones. El primero es para validar si el campo existe debe llenar los datos en el mismo formulario(model) usando (Actionlink) y el segundo botón debe registrar la información.

El problema es que al dar click al `actionlink` yo le paso un parametro pero al llegar al controlador llega como `null` y no encuentro la forma de obtener el objeto y posterior llenar el modelo a la vista(BeginForm). Sé que existe la forma de hacerlo con jquery para obtener los datos y colocarlos en el form,  pero lo que deseo hacer es usar los propios componentes de Razor si es posible.

Scripts

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegistroOrdenServicioImpo", "OrdenServicio", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <fieldset class="mb-3">
                    <legend class="text-uppercase font-size-sm font-weight-bold">Registro</legend>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Booking</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Booking, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            @*<input type="button" class="btn btn-light" value="Validar">*@
                            @Html.ActionLink("Validar", "ValidarBooking", new { @class="btn btn-light"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Observación</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Observacion, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="float-right col-sm-10">
                        @*<button type="button" id="Add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Item</button>*@
                        <a href="@Url.Action("AgregarItemImpo","OrdenServicio")" class="btn btn-primary" id="Add">Agregar Item</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            }
```

MVC

```
public ActionResult RegistroOrdenServicioImpo()
        {
            var obj = new OrdenServicioImpo();
            return View(obj);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegistroOrdenServicioImpo(OrdenServicioImpo model,string action)
        {
            //Accion a realizar
        }
public ActionResult ValidarBooking(string bookingFiltro)
        {
            var obj = metodo.validar(bookingFiltro);
            return View("RegistroOrdenServicioImpo", obj);
        }
```

En concreto quiero obtener los datos al dar clic en validar y llenar el formulario, porque no tengo problemas al registrar, solo tengo problemas al obtener la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]